# Robotic winch force sensor

Tags: motor

I have a requirement for a motor that pulls a piece of rope until the rope is taught. However I'm at a loss as to how to achieve this, I'm sure it must've been done before but I'm not sure how to best describe this in a way that would get me more results. I wondered if there are any sensors or pre-established methods for sensing resistance to motion in electrical motors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of measuring this:

- Motor current, as the resistance to motion increases the current increases linearly, you could measure the desired torque and the current and simply pull until this is met
- You could have a tensioner wheel with a potentiometer to measure when the rope is taut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know how much force should be on the rope, you could simply mount the winch against a spring that takes that same amount of force to compress.  Then, just use a limit switch to detect when the spring has been compressed.